# data contract is already present and the contracts are not equivalent

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have an interface contract, and I'm developing a WCF with this contract.

But, there is something wrong because I'm getting this error:

```
The DataContract element of type ' Contract. Xyt. ObjectWithValXyt'1
[[Contract.Xyt.LayoutXyt, Contract, Version = 2. 5. 0. 0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = null]]'
You can add to DataContractSet, since the type ' Contract. Xyt. ObjectWithValXyt'1
[[Contract.Xyt.UnitTypeXyt, Contract, Version = 2. 5. 0. 0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = null]]'
with the same data contract 'ObjectWithVal' in the namespace 'http://myhost.com/Service/2013/09' is already present and the contracts are not equivalent.
```

And this is a piece of the implementation:

```
public class Service2 : IAutomationServiceWs
{
    public List<Contract.Xyt.UnitTypeInfoXyt> GetUnitTypeInfos()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public Contract.Xyt.ObjectWithValXyt<Contract.Xyt.UnitTypeXyt> GetUnitTypeAndValidate(Contract.Xyt.UnitTypeRefXyt unitTypeRef)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public List<Contract.Xyt.LayoutInfoXyt> GetLayoutInfos()
    {
        return null;
    }
```

Why am I getting this error when I run this service on Internet Explorer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell from the error message, you have 2 different contracts with the same name (ObjectWithVal). You might try to merge them or change the name of one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do a 'Clean' before a 'Build' or debug.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't work. I get the same error.